# How to test if changes to a library break its dependents?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, devops

I'm working with 4 Spring Boot applications (each with its own GitHub repository) and a library which centralizes business logic and a services depend on.

I want to automatically compile them when a pull request is made to the central repository, so I can verify that no breaking changes are introduced. To give a little bit of context, 3 out of the 4 repos are legacy and we have no intention of updating them.

Does anyone know if this is possible with GitHub Actions?

Comment: Yes, it is possible!

Comment: You already described that you need to compile the dependent repos so you already have a solution. Did you try testing it? Facing any issues? Please update your question accordingly with all the details along with the GHA workflow(s).